# Можно ли установить bind9 на debian после установки Apache+nginx+Mysql+PHP?

Tags: apache, bind, веб-сервер, debian, linux

Суть вопроса в том, что по многим инструкциям для организации ДНС сервера и веб сервера, следует установить bind9, затем апач, nginx и остальное, я же сначала установила апач и тд, а потом вспомнила, что мне нужно прописать DNS, а значит установить bind9. Если сделать это после установки apache, работать все будет или нужно удалять апач и ставить в указанном мануалами порядке? Если удалить, то, скажите какими командами. Я очень начинающий, поэтому прошу акцентировать на элементарныx вещах, которые обычно умалчиваются из-за своей очевидности. Тк сложное и так повсеместно можно найти.

Answer (score 1):

Удалять не нужно. Они не связаны непосредственно.
Возможно придется затем перенастроить немного конфиг Апач-сервера, но не более того.

Comment: Спасибо большое. 
В конфиге Апач-сервера не нашла пока ничего сильно зависящего от ДНС и bind, попробую поставить и напишу результат сюда же.

Comment: Пишите, от ДНС там зависят все хосты и виртуальные хосты. Если они уже были сделаны, а вы хотите их перенести на ДНС, тогда придется менять конфиги.

Comment: Не нашла я - то есть у себя. То есть их не было. Ничего не было, да и ничего не стало. В итоге я поняла, что если буду с этим копаться, то не успею к сроку. 
Решение от ламера, как всегда ламерское, - переустановка сервера. В моем случае удаление VPS и создание новой.
А потом установка в правильной последовательности, и It work's как результат.